# Returning function variable error ~local variable 'user' referenced before assignment~, Python

Tags: python, function, local-variables

I've written a function and I wanted to return a variable from that function, but I keep getting an error

*local variable 'user' referenced before assignment*

My function is:

```
    def txtelm():

    # Updates date field to the current date
    if textElement.name == "DATE":
        textElement.text = strftime("%y %m %d")

    if textElement.name == "CHECK":
        textElement.text = "AB"        

    # First code block replaces the "Drawn" title block initials
    if docauthor == "Mike" and textElement.name == "DRAWN":
        textElement.text = "MM"
        user = "mm"
        #print user

    elif docauthor == "Amy" and textElement.name == "DRAWN":
        textElement.text = "AB"
        user = "ab"
        #print user

    elif docauthor == "Ian" and textElement.name == "DRAWN":
        textElement.text = "IB"
        user = "ib"

    elif docauthor == "Chris" and textElement.name == "DRAWN":
        textElement.text = "CM"
        user = "cm"

    elif docauthor == "Cynthia" and textElement.name == "DRAWN":
        textElement.text = "CC"
        user = "cc"

    return user
```

Further down my code, I call the function:

```
for textElement in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
        txtelm()
        user = txtelm()
        if textElement.name == "PATH":
        textElement.text = outloc + "\\" + sitename.replace(" ", "_") + "_" + trunc + strftime("%d%b%y") + "_" + user
```

I set some print messages to print 'user', but it doesn't seem to be returning anything. Before I created the function I had the code within it, hardcoded below the 'for loop' and it worked....so I'm stumped as to why it's not returning any values.

Any suggestions?

Comment: marginally easier to read text formatting: `textElement.text = os.path.join(outloc, "%s_%s%s_%s" % (sitename.replace(" ", "_"), trunc, strftime("%d%b%y"), user))`

Answer (score 1):

Your function takes no arguments, but uses a variable 'textElement'. You need to define your function thus:

```
txtelm(textElement):
```

and call it thus:

```
user = txtelm(textElement)
```

The the value of textElement from the loop code will be passed into the function.

I'm not sure what the first call to txtelm() is for - it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Edit:

I spoke too soon - there are several problems here. First the above, then the definition of 'user': because each definition is within an 'if', when none of them match it won't be declared at all. Add:

```
user = ""
```

to the top of your function to prevent this.

Edit again: 'docauthor' also doesn't seem to be defined - perhaps it should be another argument to the function?

Comment: Ah yes, that's because your 'return' is outside of the scope of the declaration(s) of user. Per another answer, put 'user = ""' at the top of the function.

Comment: Python doesn't have block scope.

Comment: Thanks for all the input. I revamped my if else statement to if textElement.name == "DRAWN": if docauthor == "Mike": do the rest. This seemed to have cleared it up. docauthor is a user input varaible called at the beginning of the script. Sorry for the confusion on that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that none of your `if/elif` statements are true.

Comment: do a final `else` where you raise an `exception`. Like this.. `raise ValueError(docauthor, textElement.name)`

Answer (score 0):

There's a a chance that user is never declared before trying to return it. Set user as an empty string at the start of txtelm()

```
def txtelm():
   user = ""
```

And then test if user is not empty

```
for textElement in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
        txtelm()
        user = txtelm()
        if user == "":
           #handle the error
```